# Scripting SFTP connection with expect not working

Tags: unix, sftp

I'm trying to connect to a **SFTP** server via a simple script, after looking on the web I found that `expect` might be something to look at, but for some reason I just can't make it work at all.

Here is the sample script I've created:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn sftp myuser@myftp.mydomain.com
expect "password:"
send "mypassword";
interact
```

When I execute this it still asks me for my password for some reason, even if I did send it:

```
>$ ./connect-ftp.sh 
spawn sftp myuser@myftp.mydomain.com
Connecting to myftp.mydomain.com...
myuser@myftp.mydomain.com's password:
```

Does someone have any clue as to why I can't get expect working as I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't sending a carriage return after the password.

```
send "mypassword\r"
```